# How do I get rid of a notification?

Tags: ssh, notification

I occasionally run applications that use the transparent notifications in the Ubuntu 11.10 desktop and they generally work fine for me except for when I'm running them over ssh with X11 forwarding. Those notifications dim but never disappear entirely, even after cycling in and out of the screensaver or switching to one of the other desktop panes:

[image]

Any idea what causes this and how to get rid of it? The only thing that seems to work is to log out entirely. (I've checked and I don't even have `notify-osd` installed.)

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that restarting notify-osd would solve the problem. I haven't tried this, as I can't reproduce your problem, but as far as I can understand, it should work.

Comment: Aha! That was it. (Unfortunately it didn't occur to me to check for notify-osd on the remote machine where I'm running the actual application. Duh!)

Thank you much.