# How to get rid of a notification stuck on screen?

Tags: 16.04, notification

Today I have noticed that I can't get rid of the notifications. The "Close" button doesn't seem to work no matter how many times I click on it.

At first I saw this manifesting while I was browsing using Chromium.

[image: Notification stuck in Chromium]

Then I tried Firefox - the notification was still there.

[image: Notification stuck in Firefox.]

The same thing happens with other browsers I got: Opera, Midori, Vivaldi. And even with other apps.

[image: Notification stuck in LibreOffice]

[image: Notification stuck in Apps]

[image: Notification stuck while browsing files.]

I saw that there is an [apparent duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105088/how-do-i-get-rid-of-a-notification) of this question on AskUbuntu, but the situation is obviously different.

Also, on a Google search I couldn't find anything similar except for this [question](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/notifications-stuck-on-screen-unresponsive-cannot/409105a1-0ff0-43f2-a29b-62c62f07a4f1?auth=1) on the Windows website. Apparently, in that case, the cause of all this was a malware. But I am using Ubuntu 16.04, which, as far as I know, is not (that) affected by malware.

So what could be the cause? Can you, please, tell me how to fix (and prevent) it?

Comment: @neferpitou Thank you for editing my question! I don't mind at all. ;-) And yes, I'm not a native speaker.  Truth is that I wasn't quite sure about the term I use, but I was much more interested in sharing the info regarding this technical issue than searching in dictionaries. Thank you! (Funny fate: I have moderated your edit on my question.) :-)

Comment: Update: after a simple system reboot, everything seems to be back to normal. But I am not yet sure if I should consider this an answer as I still don't know the cause of this bug.

Comment: :) you can check your notification settings from Settings Manager -> Notifications

Comment: @neferpitou That won't help. These notifications are from the web, and not native notifications.

Comment: @dobey disabling the notifications will work?

Comment: @neferpitou Disabling notifications in GNOME will have no effect, because these notifications have nothing to do with GNOME. They are browser notifications, and the browser owns the windows for them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to open Chromium, go to the advanced settings, find the *Notifications* settings, find the web site these notifications are for, and disable the notifications. You may also just disable notifications entirely, for web sites in Chromium.

There is also an advanced setting to keep Chromium running in background for some "apps," which is likely keeping the process running, and these notifications up.